# Return true if value is inserted to table in sqlite in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

How to check if value is inserted to sqlite database. Following is my code.

```
   public Boolean addToWishList(ShopingCartModel shopingCartModel) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_PRODUCT_ID,shopingCartModel.getId());
        values.put(KEY_TITLE, shopingCartModel.getCart_title());
        values.put(KEY_DESC, shopingCartModel.getCart_desc());
        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_WISHLIST, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection

        return true // if value inserted
    }
```

I want to check it something like this, if data is inserted return true, else return false.

```
if (db.addToWishList(shopingCartModel)) {
                    wishlist.setTag("selected");
                    wishlist.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_blue_24dp);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Added to wishlist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
 public Boolean addToWishList(ShopingCartModel shopingCartModel) {
 SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_PRODUCT_ID,shopingCartModel.getId());
    values.put(KEY_TITLE, shopingCartModel.getCart_title());
    values.put(KEY_DESC, shopingCartModel.getCart_desc());
    // Inserting Row
   int count = db.insert(TABLE_WISHLIST, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection


    return if(count > 0) // if value inserted
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is in your code.

The method `db.insert` will return value if insertion gets success. Otherwise, it will return `-1`.

so Your code should be.

```
if (db.insert(.......) == -1)
   //error handling.
else
   // your code
```